# Cannot receive response from Volley

Tags: android

I have this code, which populates ArrayList (Bitmap). But I am not able to receive response from Volley. I have put some logs to see the problem. I could see the last log to run was "request sent". I have INTERNET permission in my manifest, link (IMAGE_LINK) is up and running, server is not off. What could be the probably issue?

```
public class GetImages {
private ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
private ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;
private Handler handler;
private String IMAGE_LINK = "http://10.95.56.134:8084/AppServer/JSON/image_try.json";
public GetImages(Context context, Handler handler)
{
    Log.i("GetImages","Reached");
    this.handler = handler;
    this.context = context;
    prepareImages();
}
public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImages()
{
    return images;
}
public void prepareImages()
{
    RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(context)
            .getRequestQueue();
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, IMAGE_LINK, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject json) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("Response","Received");
                        Integer total = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("total"));
                        Log.i("Total",String.valueOf(total));
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < total ; i ++)
                            {
                             links.add(json.getString("image"+(i+1)));
                             Log.i("Link "+i,links.get(links.size()-1));
                            }
                        getBitmap(total);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("Error Here",e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                    Log.i("Error",arg0.toString());
                }
            });
    Log.i("Request","sent");
    queue.add(request);
}
private void getBitmap(int total)
{
    Log.i("Reached","here");
    URL url = null;
    HttpGet httpRequest = null;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < total ; j ++)
    {

        try {
            url = new URL(links.get(j));

            httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream input = null;

            input = entity.getContent();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        images.add(bitmap);
    }
    catch(Exception e) { Log.e("MyException",e.toString()); }
}
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
e}}
```

Comment: It starts with 10. But is that an internet url? It does not work in my browser. I could also have asked: where is your server running? Please tell where your android code is running.

Comment: It's my local server address. My server and the device is in same network.

Comment: Try to use that url in a browser on your device. Does it get the json?

Comment: Yes, it is fetching the JSON objects.

Comment: Ok. It will get the json text. (Not json objects). Then i do not know why you get no response. Sorry.

Comment: If you cannot get this to work then just download the json text yourself with HttpGet (like you do for the bitmaps) and then convert the json text to JSONObject. Why are you not downloading the bitmaps with volley by the way?